# Extjs4, File uplaod

Tags: extjs, extjs4, filefield

I'm tring to post file to server using Extjs4.1 filefield.

but an error occur,  it say result is undefined. :(

[image]

In form,

without filefield, it works fine.'

This is the form. and it load OK. the error occur when try to submit.

```
var myform = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    bodyStyle: 'padding: 15px 50px',
    defaults: {
        xtype: 'textfield',
        anchor: '100%',
        style : 'margin-top:10px'
    },
    items: [
    {
        xtype: 'fieldcontainer',
        layout: 'hbox',
        anchor: '50%',
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                fieldLabel: '<b>Order Number </b>',
                name: 'orderNo',
                maxLength: 9,
                flex: 1,
                allowBlank: false
            }, {
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'Get Info',
                name : 'getOrderInfo_btn',
                tooltip: 'Get Order Information',
                style: 'margin-left:5px',
                flex: 0
            }
        ]
    }, {
        fieldLabel: '<b>Refundable Tax Amount </b>',
        name: 'refundAmount',
        readOnly: true,
        labelWidth: 160,
        anchor: '45%',
        allowBlank: false
    }, {
        fieldLabel: '<b>Certificate File</b>',  //without this, it's OK
        xtype : 'filefield',  
        name: 'certificate',
        labelWidth: 160,
        anchor: '90%',
        allowBlank: false
    }
    .
    .
    .
```

This is my controller (to submit form),

```
refundTaxAmount: function (obj) {
        var form = obj.up('panel').down('form').getForm();
        console.log('Hi'); // it prints, but after that it stop with an error msg.
        if (form.isValid()) {
            form.submit({
                waitMsg: 'Please wait, now processing...',
                url: '/Order/CreditForTax/',
                method: 'POST',
                success: function (form, action) {
                    Ext.MessageBox.show({
                        title: 'Notice',
                        msg: 'The tax credit has been refunded!',
                        buttons: Ext.MessageBox.OK,
                        icon: Ext.MessageBox.INFO,
                        width: 300
                    });
                    form.reset();
                },
                failure: function (form, action) {
                    Ext.MessageBox.show({
                        title: 'Error',
                        msg: action.result.message,
                        buttons: Ext.MessageBox.OK,
                        icon: Ext.MessageBox.ERROR,
                        width: 300
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Anybody know, what is my problem? please advice me~!

Thanks

[EDIT]

when submit(), after 5-10 sec, the error message occur.

[image]

[image]

[Edit2]

ASP.NET (c#) Code,

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult CreditForTax(RefundModel info, HttpPostedFileBase certificate)
{
    object result;
    try
    {
    //do something

    result = new {success = true};
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
    log.Error(e.Message +"\n"+e.StackTrace);
    result = new { success = false, message = e.Message };
    }

    return Json(result);
}
```

yes, I think the asp.net code is wrong... anybody know what's the problem with that code?

Comment: Can you clarify if the error occurs before the form is submitted or does the file get submitted to the server but the response is not getting parsed correctly?

Comment: No before submit the error occur, so finally could not post it.

Comment: What is the call stack look like? What is it doing and where the error actually occurs?

Comment: @DmitryB I just edit my question with an more detail error message, could you review my question please? thank you!

Comment: well looks like the error is in processing response - so server must have been contacted at this point. Can you verify that the server code is processed as expected and what is the return of the server response look like?

Comment: @DmitryB Yes, you are right, I put the asp.net code into question, could you review again please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the server is using `JSON` to send the return object, then the `Content-Type` header must be set to `"text/html"` in order to tell the browser to insert the text unchanged into the document body.

**C# (MVC3) code:**

```
var jsonResponse = Json( new
                        {
                            success = false,
                            message = "Oops. There was an unexpected error.\n" + ex.ToString()
                        });
jsonResponse.ContentType = "text/html"; // <-- Set content type explicitly.
return jsonResponse;
```

Here is the link to [documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.form.Basic-method-hasUpload).